# Firebase App Distribution and Google play secure signing

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-app-distribution

I've setup [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) on our projects with the provided "App Tester" android app which is amazing. Although I identified one major issue that I know a lot of people using this tool are experiencing and from what I saw, nobody actually knows the reason behind it.

The issue is : I download my app from the Play Store. Then I deploy a new version of my App on Firebase App Distribution to test it, go to App Tester, click on my app and click on install. I get the error "Installation failed" with no more details. To resolve the issue, I must uninstall the app from my phone and click install again to have a successful install.

The reason behind this is that Android does not allow a signed APK to be updated by another APK signed with a different key.

The APK that I download from the Play Store is signed by my CI but then it is signed again by the Play Store with their [signing feature](https://play.google.com/console/about/keymanagement/) (can enable/disable it I know but I prefer to keep it enabled). The key used by Play Store to sign again my APK is private and nobody can access it.

But the APK that I upload on [Firebase App Distribution with Fastlane](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-fastlane) is signed by my CI, not Play Store. So the key is different and that's why App Tester fails installing the app.

Can't I tell Firebase to do the same process of resigning my APK with the key used by the Play Store ? It is really annoying to uninstall my app whenever I previously installed it from the Play Store. More importantly, it's annoying for the testers at my company that don't understand why they get this error and don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Question: The application that you share with your testers using app distribution, does it have the same app Id (eg. com.xyz.abc) as the one on playstore?

There cannot be two signed applications with same app id on a single device.
One of the solutions will be to update the development app id to be different than production app id.

Eg. 
Production app id - com.xyz.abc 
Development app id - com.xyz.abc-dev

This will also enable both apps to co-exist on the same device.

Comment: I'm not really into the idea of having two different apps on the testers' phones. Even if they have different names, some testers could get them mixed up and test a feature on a production APK, leading to wastes of time. My goal is to have the same behavior as iOS Testflight, on Android. It shouldn't fail because the installed APK comes from the Play Store.

Comment: Tesflight is used for beta testing. In such a case you might wanna checkout playstore beta for Android.

Comment: I said testflight because of how it works, not because I want a beta testing environment with its APK validation time. I want a Testflight-like testing app with no delay between the time I upload my APK and the time it's available for testers.